# getting server tag is not well formed error

Tags: javascript, repeater

```
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function EnableDisablePkgInclusionDropDown(chkBox,index) {
                alert("RowIndex: " + (index - 1));
                var repeater = document.getElementById('<%= pnlrptPckgInclusions.ClientID %>');
                var dropdowns = repeater.getElementsByTagName('select');
                if ($(chkBox).is(':checked')) {
                    dropdowns[index - 1].disabled = true;
                    dropdowns[index - 1].selectedIndex = document.getElementById('<%=ddlMarkUpBasis.ClientID%>').selectedIndex;
                }
                else {
                    dropdowns[index - 1].disabled = false;
                    dropdowns[index - 1].selectedIndex = "0";
                }
            }
        </script>

    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptPckgInclusions">      
    <ItemTemplate> 
<td align="center" style="width: 20%;">
        <input type="checkbox" runat="Server"  ID="chkApplyParentMarkUp" OnClick='EnableDisablePkgInclusionDropDown(this,<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>);' />
</td>
    </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:Repeater>
```

If i remove runat ="server" from checkbox then its working fine but i want this control's value in code-behind.

Why is it so??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use something like that

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkApplyParentMarkUp" OnCheckedChanged='EnableDisablePkgInclusionDropDown(this,<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>);' />
```

Because you can not define input type checkbox as `runat="server"`. And use `OnCheckedChanged` Event on behalf on `onClick` event.

Comment: its not working.showing nothing in alert("RowIndex: " + (index - 1));